# How do I create a static library in C?

Tags: c

There are two file sum.c & mul.c . I created Object Files using this command 
 `gcc -c sum.c mul.c` . Then I Created a header file with .h extension id header.h which include the signatures of  functions in sum.c and mul.c ie

```
int sum(int,int);
int mul(int,int);
```

My main program code is

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include "header.h"
void main(){
    printf("sum of 4 & 5 is %d ", sum(5,4));
    printf("mul of 4 & 5 is %d ", mul(5,4));
}
```

Now the problem is how to create  a library of the files ie sum.c & mul.c and link to the main program.

Comment: Did you at least try to find an answer before you opened your question?

Comment: @Kay yeah. i searched  static lib linking on google but the result confused me.

Answer (score 4):

Static libraries are made on linux using ar or libtool around it. For just plain C, ar is good enough. For example:

```
gcc -c -g file1.c
gcc -c -g file2.c
ar -r libmylib.a file1.o file2.o
```

To compile the main and link to the lib:

```
gcc -c -g mymain.c
gcc -L. -o mymain mymain.o -lmylib
```